# How to disable previous selected options when select option from first select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two select elements. both select have same values. when I select option from 1 select box it should disable all previous select options from second select box.
Let's suppose I have this select:

```
  <select id="s1">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>

  <select id="s2">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
```

If I select value 3 from s1 box it should disable all previous options from s2 select. if I select value 2 from s1 it should disable all previous values in s2.

**Note**: It should not disable next values, just the previous ones. I'm looking for a `jquery` solution.

Comment: How about `:lt` selector ?

Comment: can you please give more details regarding :lt? a guide to implement :lt in my case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`:lt`](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) to select elements having lesser index than specified.

[`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) will return position of the element from the matched element.

[`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) will exclude specified element from the returned elements.

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  $('select option').prop('disabled', false);
  var index = $(this).find('option:selected').index();
  $('select').not(this).find('option:lt(' + index + ')').prop('disabled', true);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="s1">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select id="s2">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/wb2xboq6/)

Comment: such an amazing little piece of code.. thank you let me implement then...i may did some mistake while elaborating my case but that gave me idea... i wanted to do in reverse order. ill use :gt :D . thank you. ill get back to you in a while. :)

Comment: @RayonDabre Learned a new thing `:lt`. +1. Enter 9k club :)

Comment: @RinoRaj, Thank you mate ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code If it is useful for you

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#s1").change(function() {
    var optVal = $(this).val();
    $("#s2 option").each(function() {
        $(this).prop('disabled', false);
        if (optVal > $(this).val()) {
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});});
```